# Rendering of unicode symbols in urxvt (height / width) vs. gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, unicode, urxvt, fontconfig

gnome-terminal renders the unicode symbols (arrows) in my prompt different from urxvt:

[image: urxvt]

[image: gnome-terminal]

[image: direct comparison]

They are displayed across the whole line's height, have less spacing in-between, but more appropriate spacing at the end (there is a space char after them).

*Edit:* the *missing space* at the end was triggered by having an escape code, e.g. `%b` for non-bold in zsh, at the end of `RPS1`. Removing it or adding a space after it fixed this particular issue.

My urxvt font config:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=16, \
    xft:monospace, \
    xft:Ubuntu Mono for Powerline
```

This applies also to other symbols like `↳`.

I have noticed that `lilyterm` behaves like `gnome-terminal` (caused by vte), while `konsole`, `xterm` etc behave like `urxvt`.

Is it possible to configure urxvt to do the same?

I am using rxvt-unicode-256color 9.19-1 on Ubuntu 14.04.
gnome-terminal is more recent (from Debian testing), and lilyterm is built from source.

An example prompt with symbols:

> ↳ git:m@o[+2]¹✗ ❯❯

Comment: Can you paste those unicode characters here?  I'd like to try to reproduce this.

Comment: @brianbaligad Sure. Added them to the question.

Comment: I suspect URxvt is not actually loading the font from your configuration.  Try starting the terminal with this command: `urxvt -fn "xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=16"` It should load the font and look as you expect it to (it did for me, at least)

Comment: @brianbaligad This looks the same. I've experimented with using an invalid name (also in the ~/.Xresources file / xrdb): this does not result in an error, but a different font/spacing.

Comment: @brianbaligad are the unicode symbols of the same height as `[`? Can you provide a screenshot, please?

Comment: Here's what I got http://imgur.com/VosZW0I

Comment: @brianbaligad That looks similar to my result in urxvt. Here is another comparison to make it clearer: [http://i.imgur.com/nCh0kAJ.png](http://i.imgur.com/nCh0kAJ.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different heights are expected, just like the issue that too wide symbols are replaced with a square symbol..

I've asked about this on the rxvt-unicode mailing list a while ago (Q4 2004), and created a patch, but it was rejected: http://lists.schmorp.de/pipermail/rxvt-unicode/2014q4/002042.html

The patch/branch is available at https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/compare/master...blueyed:display-wide-glyphs.
It will make rxvt-unicode not replace too wide symbols with a square icon, but just display them - without special handling.  Therefore you will have to add a space after it to display it completely (otherwise it gets cropped).

I've asked to include it into Arch's rxvt-unicode-patched: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rxvt-unicode-patched/